# setting ivar to custom sublassed object not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I am probably overlooking something small, but I cant seem to figure it out.

I am attempting to pass an instance of a custom class to an instance of another custom class.
**NOTE: I am using ARC***

The second custom class is set up:

```
#import "OneArtsDay.h"

@interface SocialButton : UIButton {    
    OneArtsDay *artsDay;
}

@property (nonatomic) OneArtsDay *artsDay;

- (void)setArtsDay:(OneArtsDay *)day;

@end
```

and

```
#import "SocialButton.h"

@implementation SocialButton
@synthesize artsDay;

- (void)setArtsDay:(OneArtsDay *)day {
  if (day ==nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error, cannot set artsDay");
  }
  else {
  artsDay = day;
  }
}

@end
```

Now, when I call these commands in code:

```
    SocialButton *social = [[SocialButton alloc] init];
    OneArtsDay *day = [[OneArtsDay alloc] init];
    //Do things with day here//
    [social setArtsDay:day];
```

I am still given an error when I try to access the property OneArtsDay *artsDay. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? What is not working?

Comment: instead of (nonatomic) use (strong, nonatomic) so it will keep a strong pointer to your object. This is for ARC only.. Also use the setter self.artsDay = day;

Comment: The error that I am given is an 'NSInvalidArgumentException.. unrecognized selector sent to instance..' and happens when I try to access the property OneArtsDay *artsDay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property should be declared strong.  Here's how I code the same thing:

```
#import "OneArtsDay.h"

@interface SocialButton : UIButton

// property decl gives me the file var and the public getter/setter decls
// strong tells ARC to retain the value upon assignment (and release the old one)
@property (nonatomic, strong) OneArtsDay *artsDay;

@end


#import "SocialButton.h"

@implementation SocialButton

// _underscore alias let's me name stack vars and prams the same name as my property
// without ambiguity/compiler warnings

@synthesize artsDay=_artsDay;

- (void)setArtsDay:(OneArtsDay *)artsDay {
    if (artsDay==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error, cannot set artsDay");
    } else {
        _artsDay = artsDay;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Although this is how I would do it, does it actually change anything? I thought `__strong` was the default variable qualifier, which would mean the OP's explicit declaring of the ivar was in fact declaring a `__strong` ivar. Also `strong` is more appropriate then `retain` in ARC even if they are synonyms

Comment: The class needs to keep a "strong" pointer to the object in ARC or it might get released.

Comment: I see your point, though declaring the property strong still gives me an error 'unrecognized selector sent to instance..'

Comment: can you post the code where the error occurs?  also, if you don't have one already, please add an all exceptions breakpoint... breakpoints tab in the navigator, then "+" button on the extreme lower left.